# Why are strings considered tokens in C while arrays aren't?

Tags: arrays, c, string

This is a quite basic theoritical question. I started learning the C language. I came across the topic Tokens in C.

Quoting from [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-tokens/),

> A token is the smallest element of a program that is meaningful to the compiler.Tokens can be classified as follows:
>
> 1. Keywords
> 2. Identifiers
> 3. Constants
> 4. Strings
> 5. Special Symbols
> 6. Operators

Why strings are considered as a token while arrays aren't?

Comment: Two things: First is that the geeksforgeeks site doesn't have a good reputation among experienced programmers, quite the opposite. It tends to teach bad habits, bad code and sometimes even invalid code. The second thing is that while answers from chat-AI's might look impressive, they also tend to not always be exactly correct. Especially when it comes to code, it tend to create code that looks correct and might even build without warnings, but more often than not contain something which makes it totally wrong for what's being asked.

Comment: Strings probably means "String literals"

Comment: "Each character in the string is a distinct element that can be individually accessed and manipulated, making them tokens." Lie. "...which operate on these individual characters" Lie. "there are no built-in functions specifically designed to operate on individual elements within an array" Lie. Don't ask notorious liars for help! (lAIr?)

Comment: Note to self: Add "cite Geekforgeeks on StackOverflow" to the list of how to get answers on the internet :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geeksforgeeks is almost as bad a source for learning as ChatGPT.

It is true that strings in C consists of null-terminated character arrays. But what it means to say is *string literals*, `"these things"`. That is, a constant used to initialize character arrays or to use as a read-only string.

Similarly, "constants" does not refer to things like `const int x=1;` but rather just the number part `1` - this is what formal C means when it refers to an *integer constant* (sometimes also called "integer literal" although that term is strictly speaking not correct).

Note that tokens is mostly a concept that matters when writing macros, it's not a concept that beginners usually have to worry about. The formal grammar (C17 6.4), "lexical elements", groups everything in C in these groups/sub-chapters:

- Keywords
- Identifiers
- Universal character names
- Constants
- String literals
- Punctuators
- Header names
- Preprocessing numbers
- Comments

Answer (score 4):

A token is an indivisible parsing unit.

- `;` is a token.
- `+` is a token.
- `==` is a token.
- Decimal numeric literal `4` is a token.
- Decimal numeric literal `12` is a token.
- String literal `"abc"` is a token.
- Identifier `foo` is a token.
- Identifier `int` is a token.

However,

- Strings aren't tokens because strings aren't pieces of code. (But see string *literals* above.)
- Arrays aren't tokens because array aren't pieces of code.
- Array declarations (e.g. `int a[4];`) aren't tokens because they are made of multiple other tokens.
- Array initializers (e.g. `{ 4, 5, i+2 }`) aren't tokens because they are made of multiple other tokens.

You can generally put spaces between tokens, but never within.

- `12` is not the same as `1 2`
- `"abc"` is not the same as `"a b c"`.
- `foo` is not the same as `f o o`.
- `i+2` is the same as `i + 2`.
- `{4,5,i+2}` is the same as `{ 4, 5, i + 2 }`.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering about array initialisers, and the way you've put it makes it obvious. Thank you! Of course, who'd ever want to initialise a string as {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'} ;

Comment: To complicate things further, different kinds of tokens are produced and consumed at different translation phases. At phase 3, the source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of whitespace. At phase 4, preprocessing directives can merge and replace preprocessing tokens. At phase 6, adjacent string literal preprocessing tokens are concatenated. At phase 7, preprocessing tokens are converted into tokens and any whitespace separating tokens is no longer significant.

Answer (score 3):

When the compiler processes source code, it first splits them into tokens. Example:

```
printf("%d", 4 << 2);
```

This is turned into the following tokens:

- `printf`
- `(`
- `"%d"` -- a string literal
- `,`
- `4`
- `<<`
- `2`
- `)`
- `;`

An array declaration like `int a[] = {1, 2, 3};` consists of multiple tokens, therefore it's not a token itself. The `a` here is a token though, but it's not specifically an array-token but more generally an identifier ("variable name").

Side note on `printf()`: That function itself will also kind-of tokenize the string it receives as first argument. The only distinction is whether a character is a `%` placeholder or not, so it's a much simpler. The principle stays the same though.

Answer (score 0):

It is often better to go directly to the source. The C language syntax is described semi-formally in the C Standard (C17), Annex A. The first paragraph (A.1.1) states:

```
  token:
      keyword
      identifier
      constant
      string-literal
      punctuator
```

Notice that "string-literal" is specially mentioned as a token.

As to why: the C language is built up from the same layers as a natural language: letters, words and sentences. When the compiler reads a program file, it reads the characters of the file and groups them into tokens the same way we group letters into words when reading a book. It then interprets the program as a sequence of tokens the same way as we interpret a text as a sequence of words.

A string-literal being a token is simply a decision taken by the designers of the C language because it makes sense when describing the syntax and semantics of the language.

Comment: More practically, I would imagine that string literals have to be tokens because of various preprocessor rules, such as "stringification" macros and string literal concatenation.